# WinUI ProgressRing Don't Show on WASM (Uno 2.4)

Tags: c#, uwp, wasm-bindgen, uno-platform, winui

I'm trying to add the new WinUI 2.4 ProgressRing. It works perfectly on UWP app but not show in WASM.

My App.xaml and Mainpage.xaml is:

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application
    x:Class="ACM_Search_Uno.WinUI.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ACM_Search_Uno.WinUI">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#FFCB2128</Color>
            <Color x:Key="AcmGreen">#FFB8C282</Color>
            <Color x:Key="AcmPink">#FFE672A4</Color>
            <Color x:Key="AcmPurple">#FF71749E</Color>
            <Thickness x:Key="PivotItemMargin">0</Thickness>

        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ACM_Search_Uno.WinUI"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="ACM_Search_Uno.WinUI.MainPage"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>



    </Page.Resources>


    <ScrollViewer x:Name="MainScroller" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">


        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
            <Grid.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource AcmGreen}"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="Footer" Grid.Row="2" >
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource AcmPurple}"/>
                </Grid.Background>

                <Button x:Name="HelpButton"  Margin="10,5,0,5"  Content="Yardım"  FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Background="#FF71749E" FontFamily="Noto Sans Display" FontWeight="SemiLight" Click="HelpButton_ClickAsync"  />

            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="Body" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
                <Grid x:Name="SearchGrid" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="LogoStackPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,0,10">
                        <Image x:Name="AppLogo" Source="/Assets/acm_logo.png" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderTextBlock" Text="Anahtar Kelime Arama Motoru" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,10,0,0" Foreground="#FF343434" TextAlignment="Center" FontStretch="Normal" FontSize="24" FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="Noto Sans Display" FontWeight="Light"/>




                    </StackPanel>
                    <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="KeywordSearchBox" CornerRadius="2,2,2,2" QueryIcon="Find" RequestedTheme="Dark" PlaceholderText="Lütfen anahtar kelimeyi buraya yazın" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Noto Sans Display" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="16" MinWidth="350" Margin="0,10,0,10" Grid.Row="1" MaxWidth="350"/>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="SearchButtonStack" Margin="0,10,0,10" Grid.Row="2">
                        <Button x:Name="SearchButton" Content="Ara" Foreground="#FF343434" Margin="0,10,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Click="SearchButton_ClickAsync" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" FontFamily="Noto Sans Display" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="150" MinHeight="37.5">
                            <Button.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource AcmPink}"/>
                            </Button.Background>
                        </Button>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="LanguageChangeStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,10">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="LanguageSwitchHeaderTextBlock" Text="Dil:" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FF343434" FontFamily="Noto Sans Display" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                            <ToggleSwitch x:Name="LanguageToggleSwitch" OnContent="English"  OffContent="Türkçe" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="16" Toggled="LanguageToggleSwitch_OnToggledAsync" RequestedTheme="Default" Foreground="#FF343434" FontFamily="Noto Sans Display" FontWeight="Medium"/>

                        </StackPanel>

                    </StackPanel>




                </Grid>




            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="WaiterGrid" Background="#FF343434" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                <Grid x:Name="Waiter_Item" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <controls:ProgressRing x:Name="Waiter" Width="50" Height="50" >
                        <controls:ProgressRing.Foreground>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource AcmPink}"/>
                        </controls:ProgressRing.Foreground>
                        <controls:ProgressRing.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource AcmPurple}"/>
                        </controls:ProgressRing.Background>
                    </controls:ProgressRing>


                    <TextBlock x:Name="WaiterLabel" x:Uid="Waiter_Label" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="İşlem Yapılıyor..." VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,20,0,0" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="#FFE2E2E2" FontFamily="Noto Sans Display" FontSize="22"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

*Running perfectly in UWP:*
[image]

*No any ProgressRing is available at here, different from UWP.*

[image]

ProgressRing is not available on WASM as described in [Uno Platform 2.3 blog article](https://platform.uno/blog/announcing-uno-platform-2-3-android-10-android-x-and-more/), like on UWP. It should be.

**Nuget Package Version(s):**

- Uno.UI.RemoteControl {2.4.0}
- Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap {1.2.0}
- Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.DevServer {1.2.0}
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter {1.1.2}
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Con... {1.1.1}
- NETStandard.Library {2.0.3}
- Uno.UI {2.4.0}
- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindo... {6.2.10}
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Con... {1.1.1}
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter {1.1.2}
- Microsoft.UI.Xaml {2.4.0}
- Uno.Core {2.0.0}

How can I fix this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the `ProgressRing` control, your project heads need to have a reference to the [`Uno.UI.Lottie`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uno.UI.Lottie) package.

The rendering of this control is done through Lottie, and to avoid adding unwanted dependencies, particularly on Android, this dependency in an optional package.

Comment: I was to give the same answer: yep it's required to add the `Lottie` package. You should see something in the logs saying you should add it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I have encountered a different topic, I don't know it is a bug or not. ProgressRing get stuck and won't turn around the background again after a page navigation. It looks a frozen progress ring :)

Comment: This will not work if you also reference the Community Toolkit - Uni.CommunityToolkit.winUI.UI.Controls.  If you add both, you get an error during compilation that you cannot combine WinUI and Uno UI packages in one project.

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Uno.Platform 4**:  ProgressRing is obsolete (in WASM) as a Windows.UI.Xaml control.  However, the WinUI3 version is built into Uno - you just need to reference it!

First, add the WinUI3 namespace (for the ProgressRing) to the page that is hosting the ProgressRing:

```
xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
```

and then prefix your ProgressRing tag with your newly minted WinUI3 namespace:

```
<muxc:ProgressRing Grid.Row="1" Height="100" Width="100" IsActive="True" />
```

Here's the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/8264) where the Uno dev team answers this question for version 4.0.